# Gradient stroke not appearing in PDF export file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, gradient, stroke

I’m using Adobe Illustrator and I’m having an issue with a stroke, which has a custom gradient brush applied. It’s not showing up in the PDF file after I export. It shows up just fine in web applications, but when I render it as a PDF, it doesn’t appear in the artwork upon opening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using to view the PDF? Is it by chance using a spot color?

Comment: Try using Adobe Reader to view the PDF.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Reader to view the PDF, and there are no spot colors, only process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Adobe Reader at my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the File -> Document Setup, In Transparency Box click on Custom . Slide the slider over toward rasterized until you get the proper results you need and before that also expand all gradients (optional) [image: Follow this Process]

And after that try to export it as pdf.

Comment: No go. I still get the same thing happening. =/

Comment: This might be the possible solution for me , which Version of Illustrator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem: turns out my  color formatting was set to RGB, not CMYK. I haven't the slightest clue why that makes a difference when exporting gradients in a PDF, but switching the color Profile to CMYK fixed it for me.